# Security of SFTP packages in Python

Tags: python, security, sftp, paramiko

There is plenty of info on how to use what seems to be third-party packages that allow you to access your sFTP by inputting your credentials into these packages.

**My dilemma is this:** How do I know that these third-party packages are not sharing my credentials with developers/etc?

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: Use only open-source packages and inspect the code yourself. If you lack the expertise, you can go for the safety-in-numbers argument - if there are millions of users of a said package chances are some of them are doing a proper code review and they would notice shady things the developers may have included, which would definitely raise alarms. Of course, it's not a guarantee (just look at the history of OpenSSL) but it's better than nothing, especially if you're not willing to put in the time to review everything yourself.

Comment: you dont ... you should definately look at code that you are using .... in fact there was iirc just recently a ssh package on pypi that was maliciously posting credentials to some url in poland.... in general well known packages tend to be safe ... however there is no guarantee ... (in the case i mention an attacker had maliciously uploaded a binary to pypi, that did not match the known checksum from the author)

Comment: There's no substitute for reading the source code. And that includes making sure that what `pip install` puts into your site-packages matches what you see on GitHub. If you don't have a reason to be that paranoid, you can generally assume that an old, widely-used project is probably safe, unless it's changed ownership recently, especially if it's being used by projects that have reason to be more paranoid than you are, but make sure all of those "generally" and "probably" are good enough for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for comments.

**To distill it:** Unless you do a code review yourself or you get a the sftp package from a verified vendor (ie - packages made by Amazon for AWS), you can not assume that these packages are "safe" and won't post your info to a third-party site.